# botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(61, 'Connection refused')) while running boto3 multipart API

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3, multipart

Also getting SSL error if not this. Below are the steps I tried to get rid of it but that's continuous work:

```
pip uninstall certifi
restart s3 services
```

Error message:

```
raise caught_exception
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(61, 'Connection refused'))
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and explain what are you trying to do, what is the expected result and a bit more context on the code itself?

Comment: Hi
I am trying to run create and upload a file using multipart create and multipart upload API of boto3.All these operations are being performed on a storage cluster.